# Binding 1 textbox from 2 table of access in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I tried to binding 1 textbox from 2 table in access.

[image]

I would like to when I click on item in listbox1, All of textboxs binding for listbox1. when I click on item in listbox2, All of textboxs binding for listbox2.

My idea is check item in each listbox is selected. But I can't achieve with this way. all of textboxs always binding just for listbox 1. I don't know Is there anyway to do like that.

Here is my code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Public cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public ds2 As New DataSet
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public dt2 As New DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\1_Project\Project_of_VB_Net\AccessDatabase\StudentDatabase.accdb"
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        'get data from table 1 and fill to dataset 1
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentData"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds, "StudentData")
        dt = ds.Tables("StudentData")
        'get data from table 2 and fill to dataset 2
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentData2"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds2.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds2, "StudentData2")
        dt2 = ds2.Tables("StudentData2")
        cnn.Close()
        'binding data to listbox1
        lb1.DataSource = dt
        lb1.DisplayMember = "StudentID"
        'binding data to listbox2
        lb2.DataSource = dt2
        lb2.DisplayMember = "StudentID2"

        If lb1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then 'check item listbox 1 is selected ?
            'binding textbox for listbox 1
            txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "ID")
            txtStudentName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentName")
            txtStudentID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentID")
            txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentClass")
        ElseIf lb2.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then 'check item listbox 1 is selected ?
            'binding textbox for listbox 2
            txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "ID2")
            txtStudentName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentName2")
            txtStudentID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentID2")
            txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentClass2")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**SOLVED:**

Thank you jmcilhinney, with your help, I solved my problem. You was totaly right, I had to use SelectedIndexChanged event to check and binding data when user click item on each listbox.

Here is my complete code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Public cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public ds2 As New DataSet
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public dt2 As New DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\1_Project\Project_of_VB_Net\AccessDatabase\StudentDatabase.accdb"
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        'get data from table 1 and fill dataset 2
        cnn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentData"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds, "StudentData")
        dt = ds.Tables("StudentData")
        'get data from table 2 and fill dataset 2
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentData2"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds2.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds2, "StudentData2")
        dt2 = ds2.Tables("StudentData2")
        cnn.Close()
        'binding data to listbox1
        lb1.DataSource = dt
        lb1.DisplayMember = "StudentID"
        'binding data to listbox2
        lb2.DataSource = dt2
        lb2.DisplayMember = "StudentID2"
    End Sub

    Private Sub lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lb1.SelectedIndexChanged
        txtID.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentName.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentID.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Clear()

        txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "ID")
        txtStudentName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentName")
        txtStudentID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentID")
        txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "StudentClass")
    End Sub

    Private Sub lb2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lb2.SelectedIndexChanged
        txtID.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentName.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentID.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Clear()

        txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "ID2")
        txtStudentName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentName2")
        txtStudentID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentID2")
        txtStudentClass.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "StudentClass2")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why do you have two tables in the first place? What does that data actually represent? I'd bet money that you should only have one table with an extra Boolean column to distinguish the data.

Comment: Regardless, binding in the `Load` event handler is useless. What has that got to do with clicking on an item? Nothing. You need to handle the event that is raised when the user selects and item, which is `SelectedIndexChanged`. In that event handler, you'll have to unbind the `TextBoxes` from the other `ListBox` if they are bound to it, then bind them to the current one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I tried with SelectedIndexChanged event, But it alway said error "This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.
Parameter name: binding". Could you please help me an example

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Yes, you was totally right, It's worked :)) So many thank to you